# Update XML stored in a XML column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a sample table in SQL Server 2012. I am running some queries against but the `.modify()` XQuery method is executing but not updating.

Here is the table

[image: Xml Table]

For this just trying to update settings to 'NewTest'

[image: Xml Snippet]

This will execute but nothing is updating! Thanks for any help!

[image: Not Update Snippet]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since there is a **XML namespace** (`xmlns:dev="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`) in your XML document, you must inlcude that in your `UPDATE` statement!

Try this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema')
UPDATE XmlTable
SET XmlDocument.modify('replace value of (/Doc/@Settings)[1] with "NewTest"')
WHERE XmlId = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You should declare a namespace in your update syntax .Try the below syntax

```
Declare @Sample table
(xmlCol xml)

Insert into @Sample
values
('<dev:Doc xmlns:dev="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                       SchemaVersion="0.1" Settings="Testing" Ttile="Ordering">
        <Person id="1">
            <FirstName>Name</FirstName>
        </Person>
      </dev:Doc>')
 Select * from @Sample
 Update @Sample
 SET xmlCol.modify(
                  'declare namespace ns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
                   replace value of (/ns:Doc/@Settings)[1]
                   with "NewTest"')

 Select * from @Sample
```