# How to update value of XML attributes which is saved in varchar field using SQL query?

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

We have a table called tReportTemplate and looks like

```
Table tReportTemplate (
 [ReportTemplateID] int NOT NULL,
 [CustomProperties] [varchar](7500) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tReportTemplate] PRIMARY KEY
 (
   [ReportTemplateID] ASC
 )
)
```

In [CustomProperties] we are saving report template which is a XML and looks like following -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="urn:wtxreport-1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:wtxreport-1.0" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <reportTemplate1>
    <template reportName="Demo" description="" beginDate="01/01/1901" endDate="01/01/2001" />
    <element1 att1="" att2="0" att3="0,3,5,1" />
    <element2 att4="1,4,2,6,7,5" att5="7,2,5,6,1,4,0" att6="0,1,2,3,4,6,8,9,10,11"/>
    <element3   att7="2,12,1,6,7" att8="0" att9="True" />
    <element4 att10="0" att11="False" att12="False" />
    <element5 att13="6"  att14="false" att15="0"/>
    <element6 att16="0" att17="False" />
    <element7 att18="0" />
  </reportTemplate1>
</xs:schema>
```

We have more than 10,000 records in that table. Now I need to update the value of att4 in element2 where att4 value is 6 by 2. I have searched and tried but didn't find any suitable solution. Hope someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514067/update-xml-stored-in-a-xml-column-in-sql-server you can do e4x syntax i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a little tricky to do this since your column type is VARCHAR instead of XML, but you could write a little conversion script that I think will work out.

In order for this to work, you will need to strip the < ?xml ... >, < xs:schema ... >< /xs:schema> tags out and add them back at the end when you make your final table update.

Check this out:

```
DECLARE @tempTable
(reportTemplateID INT, CustomProperties VARCHAR(7500), CustomPropertiesXML XML)

INSERT INTO @tempTable(reportTemplateID, customProperties)
SELECT ReportTemplateID, CustomProperties
FROM tReportTemplate

-- UPDATE to strip out <?xml ... >, <xs:schema ... ></xs:schema> tags and 
-- place the XML in @tempTable.CustomPropertiesXML

UPDATE t
SET customPropertiesXML.modify('replace value of (reportTemplate1/element2/@att4[1])[1] with [WhateverYouNeedToUpdateItTo]')
FROM @tempTable t

-- UPDATE to add in <?xml ... >, <xs:schema ... ></xs:schema> tags and 
-- place the now VARCHAR back in @tempTable.CustomProperties

UPDATE trt
SET trt.CustomProperties = t.CustomProperties)
FROM tReportTemplate trt
JOIN @tempTable t
  ON t.reportTemplateID = trt.ReportTemplateID
```

Comment: Hi @AlexJohnson thanks for your answer. It helped me to find the right direction. But I am facing one additional problem while updating value as path is not always same as (reportTemplate1/element2/@att4[1]). It can be (reportTemplate2/element2/@att4[1]) or (reportTemplate3/element2/@att4[1]). Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: You can try using a case statement in the update section. This is untested:
    
    UPDATE t
    SET CASE WHEN [Condition1] THEN customPropertiesXML.modify('...')
    WHEN [Condition2] THEN ....
    ELSE ..... END
    FROM @tempTable