# Query to Update exisiting XML node in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-update, insert-update

How to replace a node in the XML Column with new value.

```
Table :   Create Table ERVersion  (   
 ErVersionId    int,  
 Change     xml   
)

Insert into ERVersion  values  
(123,'<changes><change property="Custodian"><before>Group AB</before><after>Group AX</after></change></changes>')  

GO  
Insert into ERVersion  values  
(124,'<changes><change property="Custodian"><before>Group AX</before><after>Group AB</after></change></changes>')  
GO
Select * from ERVERSION
```

I need to update values in the XML Column "Change" with new values
Eg:
"Group AB" to "GROUP1"
"Group AX" to "GROUP2"...

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate, please check existing answers by searching.

You can find a related question and answer here: [Update XML stored in a XML column in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514067/update-xml-stored-in-a-xml-column-in-sql-server)

Succinctly:

```
update [tableName] set [xmlColumn].modify('replace value of (/MyXmlDoc/@XmlProperty)[1] with "NewxmlValue"')
```

For a complete reference of XML DML (Data Modification Language) please view the MSDN documentation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177454.aspx